# How to get distinct values from nested lists of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following problem:

```
foo f = new foo();
// ...
f.bars.SelectMany(m => m.qux.GroupBy(x => x.hash))
      .Select(group => group.First())
      .Sum(s => s.size);
```

This returns the sum of the total `size` property for `qux` within a **single bar instance**. Adding another `qux` object with an existing `hash` value in another `bar` is ignored so its `size` value is counted in the computed sum. (Even tho the same `qux` exists in another `bar` object).

How can I tweak my query to make sure all objects having the same `hash` are calculated once?

The data structure would look like this:

```
class foo
{
    public List<bar> bars = new List<bar>();
}

class bar
{
    public List<qux> qux = new List<qux>();
}

class qux
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide information about the structure of data you're working with.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, foo has many bars (List<Bar>) and bars has many qux (List<Qux>). Qux have two properties (size and hash).

Comment: `foo.SelectMany()` does not make sense, since `foo` is not a collection.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, thanks edited the question.

Comment: The type of `size` should be `int`, not `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your data structure, here is what you need:

```
int sizeSum =
    bars.SelectMany(m => m.qux)
        .GroupBy(q => q.hash)
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .Sum(q => q.size);
```

The difference with your initial solution is that we first get a unified list with `.SelectMany()`, and *only then* do we group it by `hash`.